# Why doesn’t -moz-border-radius-topright work in Google Chrome?

Tags: css

I want to use rounded border in my site. So, I use the CSS rounded border property like this:

```
-moz-border-radius-topright: 7px;
```

It works well in Firefox, but in Google Chrome, it does not work. Why?

Comment: There's no way you could do it in IE using CSS, you'll either have to use images or use library like Nifty Corners - http://www.html.it/articoli/nifty/index.html

Comment: -webkit for safari & chrome.
- option http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/ for all browsers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason why, is that is a Mozilla specific (i.e. Firefox) CSS selector. The relevant CSS3 selector would be:

```
border-top-right-radius
```

Webkit (i.e. Safari) also has a non-standard selector: `-webkit-border-top-right-radius`. Since Google Chrome is based on Webkit, I'd expect `-webkit-border-top-right-radius` to work.

I'd personally include all 3 selectors (as below), then you won't need to edit sometime in the future when everyone catches up with the standard. (Firefox 3.5 is already there as far as I know).

```
.thing{
...some styles...
-moz-border-radius-topright:7px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:7px;
border-top-right-radius:7px;
}
```

Comment: +1: Yup, including all of them is best for supporting as many browsers as possible.

Answer (score 14):

`-moz-`... is for Firefox etc. Use `-webkit-`...:

```
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 7px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 7px;
```

Also note the slight difference in syntax.

You can combine these as you like. `-webkit-`... will only be recognized by WebKit browsers (Chrome, Safari), `-moz-`... will only be recognized by Mozilla-based browsers (Firefox.)

Comment: True, it's not a standard property, it works on mozilla based browsers.

Comment: Indeed. Properties that are still in working drafts and have not been agreed on are usually prefixed with an identifier unique to the browser. There are also others like `-khtml-...` for KHTML based browsers.

Comment: I'd like to add to my previous comment that `-khtml-`... might work in Chrome as well, since WebKit is a forked version of KHTML.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome uses [WebKit](http://webkit.org/) for rendering, same as Safari. You'll have to add one more CSS property to your class -

```
.YourClass
{
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 7px; /* For Mozilla browsers */
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 7px; /* For WebKit-based browsers */
}
```

Comment: I want to know for IE . IE is which type of browser ? Which property to use

Comment: @aye thinzar khine: IE uses an engine called Trident. But it does not support rounded corners even in IE7. However, have a look at this: http://dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/